# Differences in jQuery's callback approaches

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am wondering about some redundant functionality in jQuery and hope someone could shed some light into it.

`jQuery.getJSON()` takes as third argument a callback function for the successful completion of the request, but at the same time `getJSON()` also returns a `jqXHR` object which also comes with three callback functions (`always()`, `done()` and `fail()`).

Now my question is whether there is any semantical difference between passing the desired function as third parameter or as argument to `done()` (also in terms of best practices), respectively if there are any advantages or disadvantages in using either. As for the latter, the only disadvantage I could imagine (even though rather unlikely as scenario) is a timing issue in case the request is processed faster than the `done()` call can bind the passed function.

Comment: The argument is a callback function, while jQuery ajax methods returns a deferred, which again has certain methods.

Comment: It's a backwards-compatibility thing. The "Promise" behavior is relatively new. They introduced it and of course opted not to break the Internet by removing the old callback version.

Comment: @Pointy So there is practically no difference? What about my timing concern?

Comment: The Promise mechanism takes care of that. If the request has completed when you call `.done()` then your callback is invoked immediately.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy, I just ran a quick test and discovered this behaviour. I guess I should read more about Promises. But about the topic, so I'd assume new code should rather use the respective functions instead of passing the function as argument, correct?

Comment: Well the new APIs really are more convenient, once you get used to them.